# Codeception tests randomly fails on redirects using click

Tags: codeception

I've got weird problem with failing codeception test.

Sometimes click method used on link/button doesn't redirect to page.
sometimes it does, but codeceptions doesn't recognize it (I see on image in output that redirect worked).
And sometimes its perfectly okay, and test runs at 100%.

I use codeception 2.2.1 version with phantomjs 2.1.1 on jenkins.

One of problematic tests:

```
$I->wantTo('verify that recent comments module are correctly presented');
$I->amOnPage('/pl/');
$I->click('.cookie-policy-info__btn-close');
$I->see('Najciekawsze opinie', '.section-title-bar');
$I->seeElement('.hp-recent-opinions.one-column-product-wrapper');
$I->seeElement('ul.slides:nth-child(1) > li > div:nth-child(1) > div:nth-child(1) > div:nth-child(1) > a:nth-
$I->click('ul.slides:nth-child(1) > li > div:nth-child(1) > div:nth-child(1) > div:nth-child(1) > a:nth-child
$I->seeInCurrentUrl('/audiobook/');
$I->moveBack(1);
$I->click('ul.slides:nth-child(1) > li > div.product-tile > div.product-tile__desc > div.product-tile__author
$I->seeInCurrentUrl('/search/author?');
$I->moveBack(1);
```

Example of `$this->titleCss() = 'ul.slides:nth-child(1) > li > div:nth-child(1) > div:nth-child(1) > div:nth-child(1) > a:nth-child(1)'`

and codeception output:

```
5) ContentModulesCest: Verify that recent comments module are correctly presented
Test  tests/acceptance/ContentModulesCest.php:recentCommentsModule
Step  See in current url "/foobar/"
Fail  Failed asserting that '/pl/' contains "/foobar/".

Scenario Steps:

8. $I->seeInCurrentUrl("/foobar/")
7. $I->click("ul.slides:nth-child(1) > li > div:n...")
6. $I->seeElement("ul.slides:nth-child(1) > li > div:n...")
5. $I->seeElement(".hp-recent-opinions.one-column-prod...")
4. $I->see("Najciekawsze opinie",".section-title-bar")
```

And on image I see that page. It's weird.
Any ideas how to stop that random fails?

Comment: Your output does not match your test, there is no seeInCurrentUrl and no seeElement in your test.

Comment: Also you missed the important part of error output which is above steps.

Comment: @Naktibalda Yes, my mistake. Just Friday

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Possibly when Codeception tries to click, that element is invisible(not loaded yet). Try to use [waitForElementVisible](http://codeception.com/docs/modules/WebDriver#waitForElementVisible) method before `click` method.

Also it could be connected with PhantomJS version. I have a plenty of weird problems with that - anything is possible.